# Запрет перечисления пользователей в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, безопасность

На wordpress 4.5.3 сайте можно узнать имя пользователя угадав его ID.
По ссылке `http://www.mysite.com/?author=1` показывает имя пользователя в адресной строке и в теге "title" формируемой страницы.
Хочу закрыть эту возможность файлом ".htaccess" делая перенаправление на страницу с ошибкой "403"
Пробовал писать в ".htaccess":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} author=\d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

Но не работает, подскажите как правильно составить код. Или может есть другой способ закрыть это

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, как минимум ошибка в регулярке, надо  `author=\d+` (иначе вы закроете только пользователей с id [0-9]), потом нужен `^` - начало строки, нужен `$` - конец строки,

в итоге получается:

во-вторых `RewriteRule   ^author/(.*)$  http://example.com/  [R,L]` с офф-сайта

гуглится по запросу `wordpress author id exposes htaccess`

Comment: @Visman,@strangeqargo спасибо. Совместил советы и получилось:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^author/(.*)$` 
`RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]`
Работает как с `^author/(.*)$` так `^author=(.*)$`, что даёт слэш?

Comment: просто слэш в пути к файлу/каталогу, он почти не обязателен, поскольку символ `.` включает и его тоже. другое дело, что тогда можно захватить другой путь, типа `author_`

Answer (score 1):

Тогда уж вот так сделайте:

```
RewriteEngine On
# это не админка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
# есть запрос переменной
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \dauthor=\d
# тогда редирект на главную, но без GET параметров 
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```

По мотивам https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46469/can-i-prevent-enumeration-of-usernames